# Problema en loop con levelplot y subplot, solo grafica la ultima figura en R

Tags: r, bucles

Quiero generar una imagen con 9 mapas, sin embargo cuando al pasar por el loop solo imprime la ultima figura.

La figura es un mapa de lluvia con isolineas de presión para 9 meses del año. Este es el cacho de mi código que buscar generar el grafico:

```
mapTheme <- rasterTheme(region = brewer.pal(9, "GnBu"))

png("mapas.png")
par(mfrow=c(3,3)
for (j in 1:9){
          plt<-levelplot(pcp_raster, margin = F, at=at.sca, pretty=TRUE, 
                           par.settings = mapTheme,
                           colorkey=TRUE,main=paste("Month",j,sep = ""))+ 
                 contourplot(slp_raster, margin = F,pretty=TRUE,colorkey=FALSE,
                             col="red",labels=list(cex=0.7),
                             cuts=6)+
                 layer(sp.lines(Mex_outline, col="black", lwd=0.5))
          print(plt)
    }
   dev.off()
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que es por `par(mfrow=c(3,3)`, intenta con `plot_grid`.

```
library(cowplot)

plot_grid(plt1, plt2, plt3, plt4, plt5,
          plt6, plt7, plt8, plt9,
          labels=c('AUTO'), ncol = 5, nrow = 2)
```

Comment: Gracias, si funcionó.